# Change color of single li on hover

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to change the font color of that particular li when hover over. My code is not working properly when mouse is pointed to li from white to black color.

```css
.tags-list li{display:inline-block;background-color:#253b5d;    padding: 1px 10px !important;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;   
    transition: all 1s linear;
    }
.tags-list li:hover{background-color: #aebdd5;}
.tags-list li a{transition: all 1s linear;color:white;}
.tags-list ul li a:hover{color:black;}
```

```html
<ul class="tags-list">
<li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It seems to work...

Comment: @Jack Bashford  No, it's not working. Font color remains white when mouse is pointed. I want to change font color to black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you added the `ul` element after your class selector that already is the `ul` element.

Compare these two lines you wrote:

```css
.tags-list li a{transition: all 1s linear;color:white;}
.tags-list ul li a:hover{color:black;} <-- .tags-list and ul is the same element and not nested
```

The first one accesses the element correctly, and the second one (which is causing the problem) does not match any elements, because it would need a nested ul element.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `ul.`, `.tags-list` already refered to the `ul`. It does not contain another `ul`.

```css
.tags-list li{display:inline-block;background-color:#253b5d;    padding: 1px 10px !important;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;   
    transition: all 1s linear;
    }
.tags-list li:hover{background-color: #aebdd5;}
.tags-list li a{transition: all 1s linear;color:white;}
.tags-list li a:hover{color:black;}
```

```html
<ul class="tags-list">
<li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `.tags-list ul li a:hover` to `.tags-list li:hover a`. The repeated `ul` in the selector was making it not match the links.

On top of that, I'd recommend putting the `:hover` on the `li` rather than the `a`, so the text color will also change if you mouse points to the padding surrounding the `a`.

```css
.tags-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #253b5d;
  padding: 1px 10px !important;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.tags-list li:hover {
  background-color: #aebdd5;
}

.tags-list li a {
  transition: all 1s linear;
  color: white;
}

.tags-list li:hover a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tags-list">
  <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

.tags-list ul li a:hover{color:black;} // this line replace by 
**.tags-list li:hover a{color:black;}**

Comment: can you provide some explanation, please?

Comment: 1. .tags-list & ul not nested.
so i have removed ul.
Also we can use ul.tags-list

2. On li hover will change anchor color so i have changed this "li:hover a{color:black;}"